# Image appear for each document instead for just one

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have two documents in collection:

`doc1`

```
id: 1
title: "example"
image: "binary numbers..."
```

`doc2`

```
id: 2
title: "example2"
```

And I have this API to return random document from collection:

```
@GetMapping("/getRandomSummerCamps")
public String getRandomSummerCamps(Model model) {
    countSummerCamps.incrementAndGet();
    if (getCountSummerCamps() <= adventureHolidaysService.countAdventureHolidays("summerCamps")) {
        AdventureHolidays photo = adventureHolidaysService.getPhoto();
        model.addAttribute("randomSummerCamps", adventureHolidaysService.findRandomAdventureHolidays("summerCamps"));
        System.out.println("in if");
        model.addAttribute("randomImage", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo.getImage().getData()));
        return "randomSummerCamps";
    } else {
        countSummerCamps.set(0);
        return "noMoreDoc";
    }
}
```

And I have this inside HTML

```
<tr th:each="randomSummerCamps:${randomSummerCamps}">
<div class="title">
    <h1>We think this trip best suit you.</h1>
    <h1 th:text="${randomSummerCamps.title}"></h1>
    <h1 th:text="${randomSummerCamps.state}"></h1>
    <div class="description">
        <td th:text="${randomSummerCamps.description}"></td>
    </div>
    <img alt="sample" th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+image}" src=""/>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.location.href = '/adventureHolidays/getRandomSummerCamps'">Randomize
        again!
    </button>
</div>
```

What is problem, image appear for both documents instead for just one, the first one where image is saved. Other fields as `title` and `state` are fine, I get them well for each document but I get image for both instead for just first document.

Comment: I think you need to add a condition for displaying the `img`. Something like `<img th:if="${randomSummerCamps.image != null}" alt="sample" th:src= ...`

Comment: That works, thanks! I didnt know I can use `if` inside html like that

Comment: Nice, I've added it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is not simple HTML, it's written in a template engine called [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/). In this engine, it's possible to add a conditional HTML tag (`<img>`) in the following way:

```
    <img th:if="${randomSummerCamps.image != null}" alt="sample" th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+image}" src=""/>
```

Now the `<img>` tag will only be present in the resulting HTML if the source image is not missing (not `null`).